# How to improve these code, about changing the directive class in angular

Tags: angular

The .ts file

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  est = true;
  barca = false;
  real = false;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  changeVal(inp: any) {
    switch (inp) {
      case 'barca':
        this.est = false;
        this.barca = true;
        this.real = false;
        break;

      case 'real':
        this.est = false;
        this.barca = false;
        this.real = true;
        break;

      case 'est':
        this.est = true;
        this.barca = false;
        this.real = false;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The .html file

```
<p [ngClass]="{'est': est, 'barca': barca, 'real': real}">class works!</p>

<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="changeVal('est')">est <br>
<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="changeVal('barca')">barca<br>
<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="changeVal('real')">real<br>
```

My intention is that, everytime someone click on the radio button barca, the barca value change to true and the others false, and so on for the others
it works but I want to know if there is a better way to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ts

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  className = '';
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  }
}
```

html

```
<p class="{{className}}">class works!</p>

<input type="radio" name="class" value="est" [(ngModel)]="className">est <br>
<input type="radio" name="class" value="barca" [(ngModel)]="className">barca<br>
<input type="radio" name="class" value="real" [(ngModel)]="className">real<br>
```

Here's what I'd do. Use the form inputs just like others to change the value of a variable, use that var to set the class of you paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, yeah, it's prettier :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for your issue, create a property that stores the class name, then on button click, just set the class name to the property.

ts

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  className = '';
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  }
}
```

html

```
<p [ngClass]="className">class works!</p>

<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="className = 'est'">est <br>
<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="className = 'barca'">barca<br>
<input type="radio" name="class" (click)="className = 'real'">real<br>
```